# How to open the password protected PDF file in word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to open the password protected PDF file into the MS word  using VBA for my requirement. I have googled lot. I haven't found any answers. How to achieve this. ? I tried with

```
Set doc = wa.documents.Open(f.Path, False, Format:="PDF Files", PasswordDocument:="ABCD")
```

But the pop up has come up. I don't want this as this should be done by programmatically. So it should accept the password and needs to be opened. I don't want any third party tool. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What you want to do is possible, but the code you tried apparently only works for password-protected word documents. Here is a very good [article](https://myengineeringworld.net/2018/04/open-password-protected-pdf-vba.html) about what you are trying. There is also a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUUX6peE11s&ab_channel=ChristosSamaras) about it.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen. This what i expected and its working fine,

Comment: I couldn't able to copy the data into Word.